# Angled Thunderbolt 2 & power adapters?

Tags: thunderbolt, power, magsafe

My Macbook's (early 2013) is placed on a tray over a shelf. The arrangement suits my purposes perfectly, but the Thunderbolt and Magsafe are sticking badly out limiting the placement of the laptop. I've got the USBs nicely out of the way with down angled adapters, and would very much prefer to do the same for the TB and Magsafe.

EDIT Thanks guys for reminding me about "ask a stupid question"...

To clarify: angled TB 2 adapters available in ebay and aliexpress, both being the same stuff. Out of 4 cheapos I've bought so far exactly one works. Frustrating, as returning the failing ones is one dreary hassle.

So, to re-phrase the question... are any angled adapters available that are known to work, or is surrendering to hit-and-miss deals the only option?

Now the second device is the angled Magsafe adapter. The T model isn't ideal, and I haven't been able to find a PSU or an adapter for Magsafe 2. I'd prefer either Magsafe 1 -style L-adapter, or downward angled one. Do those exist?

Comment: Start searching e*bay etc

Comment: Does this help? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=angled+thunderbolt+adapters&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Hi. There are no stupid questions, just that ones without documented research and specific requirements tend to get voted down or closed. We can discuss what makes a good “shopping” question in [meta] if it helps. anyone decide how to vote on or edit this question.

Comment: Given the 'obsolete' status of TB2 and MagSafe, I'd be surprised if any factory is still churning out these parts.

Answer (score 0):

MagSafe adapters are trivial to safely machine since it’s a pair of grounds, pair of conductors and DC low-voltage basic conductors.

Things get dicey when you move to angled and MagSafe USB-C adapters. The shielding and space issues make them finicky or harmful. At low data rates, the cables are not actively terminated, but the newer ones aren’t simply twisted wire pairs. Also, most are clunky and worse than the supplied cables, but to each their own preference - I could see some cases where you needed a hard stop and couldn’t accommodate a traditional cable bend.

I know of no legit / reliable / sound of engineering angled Thunderbolt adapter or cable. I suppose they could be made, just those I’ve seen are highly suspect. Caveat emptor for shopping for what you seek is my advice.

Comment: Yap, same applies to all cheapo TB2 cables I've bought. Thankfully the Apple cable works - most of the time. The problem with the straight connectors is just that when your laptop's on a tray above the desk next to a monitor, cables that poke 5-10cm directly out from the side are the ones that get finicky. Thanks anyhoo.